# Storing space into stack using memcpy instead of mallocing

Tags: c, stack, malloc, heap-memory

I am creating a linked list for a class project that stores some stock market data. I was trying to store some data onto the stack instead of mallocing to the heap. I am trying to do this using memcpy. My code is like this:

```
struct trade{

int a,b;
float c;
struct trade *n;
};
char stack[100];
int i = 0;

void newNode(struct trade **head, int a, int b, float c){
 struct trade *node;
 if(i<99){
  memcpy(&a,&stack[i],4);
  i = i + 4;
  node = (struct lnode*) malloc(16);
 }

  else 
   node = (struct lnode*) malloc(20);
}
.....
.....
}
```

My newnode function is called whenever I create a new node and I need to malloc space for it.

I copy the int into the stack array if there is still space in the stack array else I malloc into the heap. I use 20 and 16 because if I am storing the int in the stack then I need to malloc space for the remaining 16 bytes in my struct else I malloc space for 20 bytes.

For some reason I get a segfault when I do this. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: What will happen when `i` is `96` and 4th byte of the `int` is memcpy()'d ?

Comment: Well i cant be 96. because the index starts at 0 and it only increments i by 4. so i would be at 95 and on copying the 4th byte it would have reached the end of the stack array and it wouldn't go inside that if statement anymore

Comment: Why are you trying to do it this way?

Comment: Are you sure about that?  0, 4, 8, 12, ..., 92, 96.

Comment: Then would i need to use i = i + 3 ?

Comment: I am trying to do it like this because I am the project I am doing requires a lot of heap space and tends to overflow the heap. We were told to try and store some of the data on the stack to prevent that.

Comment: @user268396: I think that copying 4 byes of data into `stack` starting at offset 96 is the least of the problems here - the 4th byte in the copy will go to index 99 (96, 97, 98, 99).  However, the rest of the design seems quite complicated, and it's difficult to comprehend what the reason for the scheme is.

Comment: like I said. I am trying to do this because I am processing a lot of data and it might overlflow the heap. Hence I try to store some data on to the stack. If someone could tell me exactly how to do so I would appreciate it.

Comment: @user1320912: there are at least two problems with that reasoning: 1) you're not really storing the data 'on the stack' - the `stack[]` array is statically allocated, and 2) there's usually far more space on the heap than is available on the stack.

Comment: Then how would I store the data onto the stack ? For this assignment I am required to store some data on the stack despite how unreasonable it may sound

Comment: @MichaelBurr correct, must not have been entirely awake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You've got your memcpy arguments swapped. The destination should be the first argument:

   ```
   memcpy(&stack[i],&a,4);
   ```

   From the manpage:

   ```
   SYNOPSIS

   void * memcpy(void *restrict s1, const void *restrict s2, size_t n);

   DESCRIPTION

   The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area s2 to memory area
   s1.  If s1 and s2 overlap, behavior is undefined.  Applications in which
   s1 and s2 might overlap should use memmove(3) instead.
   ```
2. If you're compiling for anything but 32-bit x86, integers and pointers will not be 4 bytes, but e.g. 8 for 64-bit, which would cause problems. You should really use `sizeof(int)`. This will also affect the 16 and 20, which you can probably replace with `sizeof(lnode)`. These are set to the correct values at compile time, so won't affect speed.
3. Besides the issue with defining "stack" versus heap: why do you define your stack as a char array rather than int if you're putting ints in there? It's possible to use a char array, but it's a lot easier and less error-prone to just assign rather than memcpy to an array of the same type.
4. Valgrind is your friend for this kind of debugging. I find myself using it as a standard debugging tool for segfaults and memory leaks.

Comment: Might want to mention the general weirdness of trying to copy ints to a char-array, when you can have int-arrays...